# Difference between design in preview and android virtual device

Tags: android, xml, layout

[Image of XML code and Design Differnce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIsZ0.png)

In this there is a space left right of the image in AVD but in preview, space is fully covered for ImangeView
Same in case if TextView
I want the AVD design same as Preview. Is there any solution of the problem please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the layout_centerOrizontal in "true" for each graphical component. It will solve the question of horizontal align issue. But, the preview cannot show all the devices, have this in mind. So, you have to predict somehow to achieve better performance for differents functions and diffents devices.

In your case, with your example, you have to make the all components be on the center (i'm guessing that is what you want). You can work with padding too. So in order to fill the space in a better way (not too empty, like the space below the images on the first image), you can use margin and padding settings that can bring a better looking.